# Handling errors within a powershell workflow and a loop

Tags: powershell

I have got a Ps script which loops a list of servers, however the error handling is not behaving the way I would expect it to. The invoke-sqlcmd has been set to continue on error, this is deliberate because when looping through a list of servers, I dont want it to stop every time it encounters an error. On the other hand, I would like to know if there has been an error.

What I opted to do was to set the erroractionpreference to continue within the script, but the invoke-sqlcmd command set to stop. This works well outside of powershell workflows, but within a PS workflow its having undesired effects i.e If I run the powershell script from a console, I cannot see any errors if the error action is set to continue, If its set to stop then I can see the errors.

In the example below, I took out the try catch as it was masking errors.

```
Workflow RunDeployment
    { 


$file_list = @("deployment_1.sql","deployment_2.sql","deployment_3.sql","deployment_4.sql","deployment_5.sql")

$x = (1,"localhost\DEV2",3,1),(4,"localhost\DEV2",6,2),(3,"localhost\DEV2",4,3)
$k = 'serverid','servername','locationid','appid'     
$h = @{}
  
  
For($i=0;$i -lt $x[0].length; $i++){
    $x |
        ForEach-Object{
            [array]$h.($k[$i]) += [string]$_[$i]
        }
           
           
} 

$folder = "C:\Temp\"
$database_name = "Test"
$all_server_ids = $h['serverid']


    foreach -parallel ($server_id in $all_server_ids)
    {
        $ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
        $severid = $h["serverid"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_id)]
        $servername =  $h["servername"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_id)]
        $locationid =  $h["locationid"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_id)]

        foreach ($file in $file_list)
        {
        
            $release_file = "$folder$file"
            write-output "The file is $release_file "
#                try {
                invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$servername" -inputfile $folder$file  -Database  "$database_name" -Querytimeout 60 -OutputSqlErrors $true -ConnectionTimeout 10 -ErrorAction Stop -Errorvariable errorvalue 
 #               write-output "-ServerInstance $servername -inputfile $folder$file  -Database  $database_name -Querytimeout 60 -OutputSqlErrors $true -ConnectionTimeout 10 -ErrorAction Stop -Errorvariable errorvalue" 

                # if ($errorvalue){
                #     write-output "Error encountered see $errorvalue"                }
                # }
                   
            #     Catch{
            #         $error_message = $_.Exception.Message
            #         write-output $error_message
            #         write-output $error
            #     }
             }
        }
    }
        
    
RunDeployment
```

Comment: Can you describe these "undesired effects"? Does it suspend the workflow? Crash `powershell.exe`? Throw error messages? Set the computer on fire? :)

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen I have edited the post, the undesired effects are that if the erroraction is set to continue within the invoke-sqlcmd command, I cannot see any errors when executed from the console, if its set to stop then I can but it breaks the loop. What I want to be able to do is set error action to continue for the invoke-sqlcmd command and also track errors onto a variable.